# Responsive design en proyecto web

Tags: javascript

Tengo un grid en donde presento unas tarjetas y a parte tengo un sidebar y estoy haciendo el responsive para el dispositivo móvil específicamente tablets de pantalla pequeña y ya le estoy cambiando lo de la parte de las tarjetas y le hice que en un carrusel se muestren las mismas, ahora quisiera saber si se puede crear en el js algún método para que reconozca el tamaño de la pantalla y pueda activar el carrusel dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla (esto es ya que en computadoras de escritorio como en laptops el usuario puede agrandar como achicar la ventana del navegador), tengo el siguiente código en js pero creo que algo me hace falta para que sea una función constante, me pueden aconsejar en esta parte gracias.

código en js:

```
var tp = screen.width;

if (tp <= 599) {
   $('#carruselGPCi').multislider();
   $('#carruselGPCi').multislider({
      interval: 10000
   });
   $('#carruselGPCa').multislider();
   $('#carruselGPCa').multislider({
      interval: 10000
   });
}
//ya comienza a verse el tamaño normal de todas las tarjetas
if (tp >= 600) {
   $('#carruselGPCa > div:not(:first-child)').remove();
   $('#carruselGPCi > div:not(:first-child)').remove();
}
```

Comment: Utiliza los media query `@media()` de css

Comment: si en la hoja de css si los menciono, mi pregunta va más por el tema de que puedo estar modificando el tamaño de la ventana pero probando el código como está funciona una vez pero si vuelvo a modificar el tamaño ya deja de funcionar el carrusel.

Comment: No recuerdo si había un evento para el resize, pero puedes saber el tamaño de la pantalla de esta forma `Window.screen` y accedes al alto y ancho con `widht` y ` heigth`